# Ubuntu BCM43142 (14e4:4365) wireless drivers broadcom

Tags: drivers, broadcom

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 and I have a problem with the drivers for BCM43142 (14e4:4365).  I have already installed
Broadcom-STA. Version v6.30.223.271
which I got from:
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/b/broadcom-sta/
using dpkg. (4th version)
But it still does not work.

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/broadcom-sta-common_6.30.223.271-4_all.deb
[sudo] password for jan: 
(Reading database ... 204118 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../broadcom-sta-common_6.30.223.271-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking broadcom-sta-common (6.30.223.271-4) over (6.30.223.271-4) ...
Setting up broadcom-sta-common (6.30.223.271-4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.125ubuntu5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-26-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915


~$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='wl'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:977 command_do() Error running install command for wl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Operation not permitted
```

Thank You for helping

Comment: I am not sure why you'd pick that exact version. I suggest that you try this instead, the official version for Ubuntu 16.10: http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/bcmwl-kernel-source Before doing so, I suggest you remove the faulty package: `sudo dpkg -P broadcom-sta-common`

Comment: @chili555 Thanks. I retracted it.

Comment: Okay it works fine now, thank You a lot for helping!

Answer (score 0):

A current proprietary driver that works with that specific card is `wl`, see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/wl). You should be able to install it from ubuntu adding multiverse packages.